# Pass data with Razor ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need Razor @Html.ActionLink to pass data from one page to another. The Action link is like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to Plan","Index","Plan", null, new {@id="submit", @name="submit", @class="slider-btn"})
```

I have a value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" value="some_value" />
```

Comment: Replace the 4th parameter of your `ActionLink()` with the data you want to pass - e.g. `@Html.ActionLink("Add to Plan","Index","Plan", new { searchbar = "some_value" }, new { ... })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should use this...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to Plan","Index","Plan", new { searchbar = "some_value" }, new { ... })
```